# ERROR: Service 'dotnetsdk' failed to build : Build failed

Tags: container, setup

I am getting `failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory ERROR: Service 'dotnetsdk' failed to build : Build failed`, when running up.ps1 in step 7 of Create the MyProject solution in [the Sitecore 10 Getting Started Template](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html).

**Env**

- Powershell running in admin, version 5.1
- .Net Framework version 4.8
- .Net core SDK version 3.1
- Docker Desktop 4.11

**Console output**

```
PS D:\Lencia\MyProject> .\up.ps1
Building containers...
solr uses an image, skipping
mssql uses an image, skipping
traefik uses an image, skipping
Building dotnetsdk
[+] Building 825.2s (4/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.98kB                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019                                                                                                                                  1.2s
 => ERROR [1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019@sha256:2d315059f5704a09c75dc45e12352e6a53ad6a208fdd5e79c4005dcdac1ac1de                                                                    823.9s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019@sha256:2d315059f5704a09c75dc45e12352e6a53ad6a208fdd5e79c4005dcdac1ac1de                                                                            0.0s
 => => sha256:49067b9f938ad8183436027e0cbb1b4becb6d1b7e75669cb6b3cab2218240004 11.08kB / 11.08kB                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => sha256:b111c3320c949bea81612bf4554f1b6592c2f504920b5bf57ba340a1d4d52c93 1.88GB / 1.88GB                                                                                                                                        654.1s
 => => sha256:2d315059f5704a09c75dc45e12352e6a53ad6a208fdd5e79c4005dcdac1ac1de 2.79kB / 2.79kB                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:7aca8de30754f19fe03ee4c21eed0762efb5e91bf684b0cc36cc92b2af13446d 794.88MB / 794.88MB                                                                                                                                    192.0s
 => => sha256:187da2dbc6618d05b13d2081df50cfa22914ddd6ff7b2c3e42fd3717038487c4 1.29kB / 1.29kB                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => sha256:eb5fc0ce360f49b58a93bee8f973f955c4566f60fe1f2b4642d9478f495c888a 930.71MB / 930.71MB                                                                                                                                    252.5s
 => => sha256:b283d0205c7122edc4f8364c15ceaa42aedd4111684e9e6ad55bcf070629ef47 1.29kB / 1.29kB                                                                                                                                        192.6s
 => => sha256:761cd75a4b44c045d4c93f18144d31a6803209432067e02c2bb46e0527d3fdbf 8.02MB / 8.02MB                                                                                                                                        195.5s
 => => sha256:50c2f63f30821afc04b2356e564875f0a5f97ab9a432c230fe2e14725ff0c88d 1.65GB / 1.65GB                                                                                                                                        627.7s
 => => sha256:0df54937d9b2ef12ef1a7055d4a6912fb85f8adde65284cd31251f7c6533caa2 619.55kB / 619.55kB                                                                                                                                    253.3s
 => => sha256:d77a88ab318d259831fe167bd0332cb25668f5503a25b60f3f8544bc040d8879 167.61MB / 167.61MB                                                                                                                                    326.0s
 => => sha256:16a57bb2ad223b843bd8aeb119680817b303b14d04f2e73971a36328da978942 1.30kB / 1.30kB                                                                                                                                        326.5s
 => => extracting sha256:b111c3320c949bea81612bf4554f1b6592c2f504920b5bf57ba340a1d4d52c93                                                                                                                                             129.2s
 => => extracting sha256:7aca8de30754f19fe03ee4c21eed0762efb5e91bf684b0cc36cc92b2af13446d                                                                                                                                              39.3s
------
 > [1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019@sha256:2d315059f5704a09c75dc45e12352e6a53ad6a208fdd5e79c4005dcdac1ac1de:
------
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'dotnetsdk' failed to build : Build failed
D:\Lencia\MyProject\up.ps1 : Container build failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1
```

Do you have any ideas about this issue? Did I do any wrong?
Thank for your support!

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix this error, you should move to `Windows containers`.

- Right-click the **Docker Whale icon**
- Choose "**Switch to Windows containers...**"
- Hit "**Switch**". If the process fails, let `Docker Desktop` restart itself and retry. The reason why Docker may crash, is that it has active containers running in the background. Don't worry about it and just retry.
- Wait for the process to finish. When the **Docker Desktop** is green again, in the lower-left corner, you're good to go.

Try this, hope this solved your issue.

Comment: Please accept the answer if your issues resolve. And please remove your comment in the answer section as this is only used if you have an answer for this. What you have written is a comment that can be used under the answer or question using Add a Comment link. Thanks

Comment: You can accept the answer using the right (correct) icon below the upvote and downvote links. Thanks

Comment: It works for me after Switch to Windows containers. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks can you accept the answer using a tick mark below the up and down arrow. So other users can know that the answer is accepted by you.  @NhanNguyen

Comment: I am facing the same error when running on a Windows container on a OpenShift Cluster, below is the question posted,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886588/docker-windows-build-file-not-found